# Determining Pitch of 何より from Accent Dictionaries

Tags: pitch-accent, dictionary

I'm trying to learn how to determine the pitch accent of words from monolingual accent dictionaries. In this case the word in question is 何より, which can have Atamadaka or Heiban pitch. According to my list of dictionary entries, this word has two forms: no-adj form, and adverb form:

> [image]

**Question 1:** Am I correctly parsing that this word can take either Atamadaka or Heiban pitch as either a no-adj or adverb?

**Question 2:** What is meant by the "それは~だ" entries? Is "何より" supposed to be filled in place of "~"?

Comment: The app aggregates entries from multiple dictionaries? 3-5 (and perhaps 1) seem the same meaning.

Comment: And to make it even worse, they are all just different versions of the same dict lol. There is zero value in having outdated versions of NHK, just remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that 1. is accent [0] な↑により, while 2, 3, 4, 5 are accent[1] な↓により. However, the pitch accents my vary according to the region and they are not so strict. I am from Kyoto (Western Japan).

Comment: Why do you think (1) is accent [0]? There doesn't seem to be any marking indicating this, right? Or are you just using your outside knowledge of Japanese?

Comment: I'm a native speaker of Japanese language. When I say なにより for 1, my accent is 0. But actually this accent is not so strict in Japanese language, and it varies by region. I'm from Kyoto (Western Japan) so my accent is 0 for 1. I think this accent emphasize "more than". Thank you.

Comment: I’m from Tokyo (Eastern Japan).Accent [1] for all.  But the accent [0] for 1 is totally fine if someone say that way.   It gives me the western vibe.